# Get all Keys:Values from Chrome Storage

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I got all keys from Chrome Storage by passing **null** as object.

For example,

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, callbackFunction); //list of Object property
```

Is there any way similarly to get all **property:propertyValues** pairs from Chrome Storage?

Comment: What do you mean all `keys: values`? Chrome storage will return you a single object will all the stored data.

Comment: I mean, how to get all property:propertyValues in an Object.

Comment: `chrome.storage.local.get(function(items) { console.log(items) });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
   for (key in items) {
       //do stuffs here
   }
});
```

I achieved through **for** loop